# Sending students for conference presentation with no additional funding

Tags: conference, funding

Me with my two students got a paper accepted at a high-ranked CS conference. We have to register for the conference along with travel for presentation and other formalities.

I instructed my students to finish the formalities such as register, book for air tickets etc.

However, I find that I don't have fund presently to book for air tickets and do the registration. Although, they agreed for the process, I am not feeling relaxed on this situation.

Did I do justice for this situation?

*However, I told them that we can look for some travel grants after the tickets are booked.*

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your situation.  Did you tell your students that you don't have funding for them?  You certainly need to. If you did, did you discuss whether they are able and willing to cover the costs themselves if necessary?  You certainly need to.  Also, how did you get into this situation?  What was your plan for the funding when you submitted the paper?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I was expecting some funding by the time we receive the decision. But, bad! Yes, I did discuss with my students about it and they agreed to do arrange those themselves.

Comment: How are you paying for yourself to go to the conference?

Comment: It might be worth only one of you going, so that the paper gets published.  This should save on costs. If your student is willing to go alone that might be best. Does your school have any funding sources for this?

Comment: @RichardKavanagh Yes there is some funding from the school almost 50℅

Comment: I don't have enough to justify a full answer, but you should probably stop thinking about the administrative stuff (travel, registration, etc.) as a "formality". Your students are now in a position where they have been asked to attend a conference that you can't fund. Does it feel like a formality to them?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to make some of the conference cheaper overall. To give an example some IEEE conferences registration fees are very expensive, this can't be avoided. The last one I attended was also in an expensive hotel. It may be possible to get other accommodation further away and travel in. They may ask for student helpers as well, which could add extra discounts. Early booking may give early bird registration fees as well. The flights, which I assume are required equally might be cheaper in advance.

Comment: Also, some conferences offer a reduced rate to students, or to authors from economically disadvantaged countries.